# Extending layers of nodes in neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two node types "Person" and "Company". There is also a relationship called "Shareholder", which can be from Person to Company or Company to Company (as companies can also hold shares in other companies). The Shareholder relationship has three properties "shareholding_start_date", "shareholding_end_date", "number_of_shares".

I have a query which takes in Company name (call it 'ABC'), as well as provide a date (e.g. '2021-07-23'), and the query returns all Person/Company nodes that are shareholders of c at the date '2021-07-23' (i.e. shareholding_start_date < 2021-07-23 < shareholding_end_date). It also calculates the percentage based on 'number_of_shares'.

The working query is below:

```
MATCH (c:Company {name:”ABC”})<-[r:Shareholder]-(s)
WHERE R.shareholding_start_date <= Date(“2021-07-23”) 
   AND r.shareholding_end_date >= DATE(“2021-07-23”)
WITH c, 
collect(s) as shareholders, 
collect(r) as rels, 
sum(r.number_of_shares) AS totalShares
UNWIND range(0, size(rels) - 1) AS I
RETURN shareholders[i].name AS shareholder, 
100.0 * rels[i].number_of_shares/totalShares as percentTotalShares
```

I am looking to extend this so that it also shows shareholders of shareholders, up to a certain layer limit which can be defined in the query (let's say 3, for example). So in the above example, the query will return all shareholders of company 'ABC', which may be "Person" or "Company" node types. In the case where the shareholders of 'ABC' are "Company" nodes, I basically want to repeat the same code on them and list all their Shareholders, along with the shareholding % in that company. This should continue until we reach the limit (i.e. 3).

Comment: Your use case is actually very complicated and nuanced, and you may need to adjust the data model. There are many questions raised. 1. Does the date constraint have to hold for every relationship in the path to "ABC"? 2. Does `shareholding_end_date` always exist? If so, what value is used if the shares have not been sold yet? 3. If an entity sells only a portion of its shares from a purchase, how is that represented by your data model? 4. Is `totalShares` for a company supposed to be the total shares *regardless* of purchase date?

Comment: It would also be helpful for you to provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Assumptions

1. The date constraint is applied to all relationships in every path to the specified company ("ABC").
2. The end date property does not exist if shares are still currently held.
3. If an entity sells only a portion of its shares from a given purchase, the end date property is added, the number of shares is reduced to the number sold, and the remaining shares are used to create a new relationship with the same start date. (This is not implemented in my answer, since the use case does not sell any shares).
4. The date constraint is also enforced when calculating `totalShares` for a company.
5. A company can hold some of its own shares.
6. You pass the target date and company name in the [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) `$targetDate` and `$company`.

#### Data model

I simplified the names in the data model for easier reading:

```
(:Person|Company {name})-[:HOLDS {start, end, shares}]->(:Company {name})
```

#### Cypher query

Here is one way to implement your use case:

```
WITH DATE($targetDate) AS targetDate

// Find all paths up to length 3 involving the specified company, on the target date.
MATCH ()-[rs:HOLDS*..3]->(:Company {name: $company})
WHERE ALL(r IN rs WHERE r.start <= targetDate AND (r.end IS NULL OR targetDate <= r.end))

// Collect the distinct HOLD relationships in the paths for each company.
WITH targetDate, ENDNODE(rs[0]) AS c, COLLECT(DISTINCT rs[0]) AS rels

// Calculate total number of shares owned by each company in the paths, on the target date
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH c, rels, SUM(rel.shares) AS totalShares

// Return a company, a shareholder, and the percentage of that company owned by the shareholder on the target date.
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH totalShares, c.name AS company, STARTNODE(rel).name AS holder, SUM(rel.shares) AS shares
RETURN company, holder, 100.0*shares/totalShares AS pct
```

#### Test data

```
CREATE (p1:Person {name: 'John'}),
       (p2:Person {name: 'Dave'}),
       (p3:Person {name: 'Alice'})

CREATE (c1:Company {name: 'Comp1'}),
       (c2:Company {name: 'Comp2'}),
       (c3:Company {name: 'Comp3'}),
       (c4:Company {name: 'ABC'})

CREATE (p1)-[:HOLDS {start: date('2018-01-01'), end: date('2022-12-31'), shares: 1000}]->(c1)
CREATE (c2)-[:HOLDS {start: date('2020-01-01'), end: date('2025-12-31'), shares: 750}]->(c1)
CREATE (p3)-[:HOLDS {start: date('2019-01-01'), end: date('2022-12-31'), shares: 800}]->(c3)
CREATE (c1)-[:HOLDS {start: date('2016-07-01'), end: date('2023-12-31'), shares: 800}]->(c4)

// Dave bought 500 shares of Comp1, and later bought 250 more.
// Then he sold 125 shares from the second batch on '2023-06-30' and still has the remaining 125 shares.
CREATE (p2)-[:HOLDS {start: date('2020-01-01'), end: date('2023-12-31'), shares: 500}]->(c1)
CREATE (p2)-[:HOLDS {start: date('2023-01-01'), end: date('2023-06-30'), shares: 125}]->(c1)
CREATE (p2)-[:HOLDS {start: date('2023-01-01'), shares: 125}]->(c1)

// ABC and Comp2 own shares of each other
CREATE (c2)-[:HOLDS {start: date('2017-01-01'), end: date('2023-12-31'), shares: 700}]->(c4)
CREATE (c4)-[:HOLDS {start: date('2016-07-01'), shares: 500}]->(c2)

// Comp1 holds (and continues to hold) some of its own shares
CREATE (c1)-[:HOLDS {start: date('2021-01-01'), shares: 500}]->(c1)
```

#### Results

Using `$targetDate` = "2023-07-21", and `$company` = "ABC":

```
╒═══════╤═══════╤══════════════════╕
│company│holder │pct               │
╞═══════╪═══════╪══════════════════╡
│"ABC"  │"Comp2"│46.666666666666664│
├───────┼───────┼──────────────────┤
│"ABC"  │"Comp1"│53.333333333333336│
├───────┼───────┼──────────────────┤
│"Comp2"│"ABC"  │100.0             │
├───────┼───────┼──────────────────┤
│"Comp1"│"Comp2"│40.0              │
├───────┼───────┼──────────────────┤
│"Comp1"│"Dave" │33.333333333333336│
├───────┼───────┼──────────────────┤
│"Comp1"│"Comp1"│26.666666666666668│
└───────┴───────┴──────────────────┘
```

#### Matching graph

Here is a graph of the paths found by the above query's first `MATCH`/`WHERE` pair.

[image]

Here is the visualization query (a minor variant of the first 3 clauses of above query):

```
WITH DATE($targetDate) AS targetDate
MATCH (h)-[rs:HOLDS*..3]->(c:Company {name: $company})
WHERE ALL(r IN rs WHERE r.start <= targetDate AND (r.end IS NULL OR targetDate <= r.end))
RETURN *
```

Comment: Thanks @cybersam! Just one question, instead of returning the values, is there any way I can update an existing relationship attribute (called holding_pct) with the values?

Comment: That is probably not a good idea. A holder can have multiple `HOLD` relationships to the same company, and it does not seem sensible to put a holder's _total_ percentage in that company in each `HOLD`. Also, you'd have to recalculate _every_ `HOLD` percentage for a company whenever _any_ of its shares are bought or sold, which is _a lot_ of overhead, especially if nobody cares about most of the results. It would make much more sense to just do the calculation as needed.

Comment: thanks! There's just one thing I'm struggling with. I'm not able to visualise the graph like you for some reason. The query just returns a table without showing the graph. Do you know how I can get your visualisation in the picture you shared?

Comment: My full query does not return nodes, relationships, or paths; so the Browser has nothing to visualize. As I tried to indicate in the `Matching graph` section, the visualization in that section comes from the "first MATCH/WHERE pair". See the bottom of my updated answer.